# How to make taskbar more transparent in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

I just installed Windows 10 the other day.  I came from Linux and am surprised by how uncustomizable Windows is.  I want to add more transparency to the taskbar, but I can't figure out how.  Is it possible, and if so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [classic shell](http://www.classicshell.net/) to do this. There's an option in there that will allow you to make the taskbar transparent to whatever level you want.

**Procedure:**

1. Download and install Classic Shell (above link)
2. Open 'Classic Start Menu Settings'
3. Check the box labeled 'Show all settings'
4. Click on the tab labeled 'Taskbar'
5. Set a color and opacity

Note: you may want to remove some of the things Classic Shell does by default - doing so shouldn't be too difficult, just look around the settings.

Comment: Beware, because this one reportedly has been compromised some time ago.(https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/4vw21h/massive_psa_do_not_download_classic_shell_read/, 2016-08).

Comment: Ah yeah, don't worry about that anymore I believe it was recently fixed. I'm using it on my PC and had no issues.

Comment: @illage4: That is not a sufficient debunking of a report of being compromised!

Comment: This is the method I used and it worked great, and also gave me some other things to try out, thus this is the answer I've accepted.  Thank you :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: FossHub, the download mirror of Classic Shell was compromised, not the software itself. Now Classic Shell has switched to mediafire.

Comment: @jingyu9575 That's better!

Comment: It's Safe as stated by the developers.  http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=6441&sid=fd38e9862219f9d6125bffe360c290a6

Answer (score 20):

Here are two ways to modify the registry to make the taskbar more transparent:

**Method 1**

1. Click on the Start Menu and type `regedit` and hit Enter
2. Navigate to the following key:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced

3. Right-click on the `Advanced` subkey in the left window pane
4. Go down to New and select `DWORD (32-bit) Value`
5. Name the new value `UseOLEDTaskbarTransparency`
6. Now double-click on the value you just renamed
7. In the new window enter 1 in the Value Data field
8. Click OK and then reboot your PC

**Method 2**

If you don't feel like doing it manually through the registry, you can use a [Taskbar Transparency Hack (`.reg` file)](http://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Taskbar-Transparency-Hacks.zip) from [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/258681/how-to-make-the-windows-10-taskbar-more-transparent/) that does the exact same thing descrived above but this way you just have to double-click the .reg file contained in the zip download and it will import the key automatically. You will need to reboot after doing this method as well.

Comment: Instead of rebooting, you can also press `Win`+`I` and go to Personalisation > Colours and [toggle off/on any of the colour settings](http://www.howtogeek.com/258681/how-to-make-the-windows-10-taskbar-more-transparent/) (this will save into the registry and considers the new value that you created in there).

Comment: This is the most useful answer as this does not involve any 3rd party software.. +1

Answer (score 6):

I use [StartIsBack++](http://startisback.com/) to have more control over the taskbar. In the StartIsBack++ options you can make Taskbar transparent and add blur

[image]

to it like in Windows 7

[image]